# Repeated value of position - GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am working on an Android Application , here I need to display data in the GridView , The problem I am facing now is that value of **position** variable is repeating inside the *getView(int **position**, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)* method of the subclass of **BaseAdapter** . I tried to find out the issue after removing additional code from the subclass , still result is the same . I visited similar posts on stackoverflow but no luck .

Here is the code of LazyAdapter (subclass of BaseAdapter)

```
    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context ctx;
            private List<ItemDetails> items;
            BooksViewHolder booksViewHolder = null ;

            public LazyAdapter(Context context, List<ItemDetails> arrayList) {
                super();
                ctx = context;
                this.items = arrayList;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return items.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return items.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return items.indexOf(getItem(position));
            }

            class BooksViewHolder{
                RelativeLayout containerLayout , playout , prelayout , offlinetext , thumblayout ;
                TextView text , priceText;
                ImageView image ;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if(convertView==null) {
                    booksViewHolder = new BooksViewHolder();
                    booksViewHolder.prelayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prelayout);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookcontent, null);
                    booksViewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookname);
                    booksViewHolder.priceText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricetext);
                    convertView.setTag(booksViewHolder);
                } else {
                    booksViewHolder = (BooksViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

            prelayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                bookClickListener.onBookClick(position);
            }});

                return convertView;
            }

            interface OnBookClickListener{
                void onBookClick(int bookPosition);
            }

            public void setOnBookClickListenre(OnBookClickListener clickListener){
                bookClickListener = clickListener ;
            }

        }
```

MyActivity.java :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LazyAdapter.OnBookListener{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
        //Code to get the reference of Gridview .
        // set the listener on Gridview 
    }

  @Override
    public void onBookClick(int position){
    BookModel book= lazyadapter.getItems().get(position);

   //Here due to incorrect position I am not able to get particular book .
}

}
```

Help me please , I am not able to figure out the issue .

Comment: it is actually OK that `getView` is called several times for the same position. It can happen because of many reasons. You just have to have it in mund

Comment: the code looks ok so far (the only thing which might cause problems is getItemId() in the case that one item object instance is added to the items list several times, but I suppose your books are all different) Is there anything not working as expected from a user''s point of view?

Comment: @0X0nosugar there is no issue in data which gridview is displaying on the screen . The issue is that , I am not able to access accurate position when I set click event on prelayout , due to repeated value of position I am not able to fetch accurate book from items .

Comment: @VladMatvienko Gridview is displaying accurate data on the screen , but the issue is that when I set click on prelayout then I am not able to access accurate book from items due to repeated value of position .

Comment: Sorry but so far I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve and when this should happen. The "pre-layout" seems to me like something related to RecyclerView, and here we have a GridView which works differently. Could you add some more code snippets to show how you're trying to access the specific book?

Comment: No , prelayout is not related to recyclerview , it is just a RelativeLayout , I have put it inside the getView in above code .

Comment: I did not notice the edit, my bad :(  - But wait a minute, this will crash if (convertView == null) The line has to come after the "inflate..." OK, now I think I understand what may be the problem. Could you add the code for the onClickListener?

Comment: Yes I am adding more code .

Comment: @0X0nosugar Additional code added to make it more clear .

Comment: Thanks, I'll set up a small sample to make sure I can fix it - may take a liitle while ;)

Comment: Thanks @0X0nosugar I will wait for sample code .